# Node js async/await promise problem with ytdl and ffmpeg

Tags: javascript, node.js, ffmpeg, promise, async-await

I built a simple youtube downloader cli. It looks like this (without any arg parsing for easier reproduction):

```
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');
const config = require('config');
const progressBar = require('./progressBar');
const logger = require('./logger');
const ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');

const url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Np8ibIagn3M';

const getInfo = async (url) => {
    logger.info(`Getting metadata for ${url}`);
    const response = await ytdl.getBasicInfo(url);
    const info = response.videoDetails.title;
    logger.info(`Title: ${info}`);
    return info;
};

const getStream = async (url) => {
    logger.info(`Downloading from ${url} ...`);

    let allReceived = false;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const stream = ytdl(url, {
            quality: 'highest',
            filter: (format) => format.container === 'mp4',
        })
            .on('progress', (_, totalDownloaded, total) => {
                if (!allReceived) {
                    progressBar.start(total, 0, {
                        mbTotal: (total / 1024 / 1024).toFixed(2),
                        mbValue: 0,
                    });
                    allReceived = true;
                }
                progressBar.increment();
                progressBar.update(totalDownloaded, {
                    mbValue: (totalDownloaded / 1024 / 1024).toFixed(2),
                });
            })
            .on('end', () => {
                progressBar.stop();
                logger.info('Successfully downloaded the stream!');
            });
        return resolve(stream);
    });
};

const convertToMp3 = async (stream, title) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        ffmpeg({ source: stream })
            .output(`${config.get('audioDir')}/${title}.mp3`)
            .audioBitrate('192k')
            .run();
        return resolve();
    });
};

const main = async (url) => {
    const info = await getInfo(url);
    console.log('here 1');
    const stream = await getStream(url);
    console.log('here 2');
    await convertToMp3(stream, info);
    console.log('done');
};

main(url);
```

The output looks like:

```
➜ node youtube.js
info:    Getting metadata for https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Np8ibIagn3M
info:    Title: Tu boca -  (Bachata Remix Dj Khalid)
here 1
info:    Downloading from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Np8ibIagn3M ...
here 2
done
[Progress] [████████████████████████████████████████] 100% | Downloaded: 7.15/7.15 MB | Elapsed Time: 5s
info:    Successfully downloaded the stream!
```

However, I would expect this output:

```
➜ node youtube.js
info:    Getting metadata for https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Np8ibIagn3M
info:    Title: Tu boca -  (Bachata Remix Dj Khalid)
here 1
info:    Downloading from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Np8ibIagn3M ...
[Progress] [████████████████████████████████████████] 100% | Downloaded: 7.15/7.15 MB | Elapsed Time: 5s
here 2
info:    Successfully downloaded the stream!
done
```

I think I have troubles to understand async/await. As far as I understood, promisifying a function allows me wait for the result. However, it seems that it does not work. I do not know why and how to properly debug it.

EDITED:

```
const getStream = async (url) => {
    logger.info(`Downloading from ${url} ...`);

    let allReceived = false;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const stream = ytdl(url, {
            quality: 'highest',
            filter: (format) => format.container === 'mp4',
        })
            .on('progress', (_, totalDownloaded, total) => {
                console.log('totalDownloaded: ' + totalDownloaded);
                if (!allReceived) {
                    console.log('total: ' + total);
                    progressBar.start(total, 0, {
                        mbTotal: (total / 1024 / 1024).toFixed(2),
                        mbValue: 0,
                    });
                    allReceived = true;
                }
                progressBar.increment();
                progressBar.update(totalDownloaded, {
                    mbValue: (totalDownloaded / 1024 / 1024).toFixed(2),
                });
            })
            .on('end', () => {
                progressBar.stop();
                logger.info('Successfully downloaded the stream!');
                resolve(stream);
            });
    });
};
```

But now it is like this:

```
➜ node youtube.js
info:    Getting metadata for https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Np8ibIagn3M
info:    Title: Tu boca -  (Bachata Remix Dj Khalid)
here 1
info:    Downloading from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Np8ibIagn3M ...
[Progress] [██████░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░] 14% | Downloaded: 1.02/7.15 MB | Elapsed Time: 52s
```

Added console.log:

```
totalDownloaded: 16384
total: 7493903
[Progress] [░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░] 0% | Downloaded: 0/7.15 MB | Elapsed Time: 0stotalDownloaded: 32768
totalDownloaded: 49152
totalDownloaded: 65536
totalDownloaded: 81920
totalDownloaded: 98304
totalDownloaded: 114688
totalDownloaded: 131072
totalDownloaded: 147456
totalDownloaded: 163840
totalDownloaded: 180224
totalDownloaded: 196608
totalDownloaded: 212992
totalDownloaded: 229376
totalDownloaded: 245760
totalDownloaded: 262144
totalDownloaded: 278528
totalDownloaded: 294912
totalDownloaded: 311296
totalDownloaded: 327680
totalDownloaded: 344064
totalDownloaded: 360448
totalDownloaded: 376832
totalDownloaded: 393216
totalDownloaded: 409600
totalDownloaded: 425984
totalDownloaded: 442368
totalDownloaded: 458752
totalDownloaded: 475136
totalDownloaded: 491520
totalDownloaded: 507904
totalDownloaded: 524288
totalDownloaded: 540672
totalDownloaded: 557056
totalDownloaded: 573440
totalDownloaded: 589824
totalDownloaded: 606208
totalDownloaded: 622592
totalDownloaded: 638976
totalDownloaded: 655360
totalDownloaded: 671744
totalDownloaded: 688128
totalDownloaded: 704512
totalDownloaded: 720896
totalDownloaded: 737280
totalDownloaded: 753664
totalDownloaded: 770048
totalDownloaded: 786432
totalDownloaded: 802816
totalDownloaded: 819200
totalDownloaded: 835584
totalDownloaded: 851968
totalDownloaded: 868352
totalDownloaded: 884736
totalDownloaded: 901120
totalDownloaded: 917504
totalDownloaded: 933888
totalDownloaded: 950272
totalDownloaded: 966656
totalDownloaded: 983040
totalDownloaded: 999424
totalDownloaded: 1015808
totalDownloaded: 1032192
totalDownloaded: 1048576
totalDownloaded: 1064960
[Progress] [██████░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░] 14% | Downloaded: 1.02/7.15 MB | Elapsed Time: 25s
```

Comment: Please can you add a console.log to the progress event which logs the arguments? Just curious

Comment: Just added the console.log statements

Comment: Funny how it stops at almost exactly a Mebibyte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used promises correctly, but you seem to want a different output. This is what happens inside `getStream()`:

1. Log "Downloading from ${url}".
2. Create a Promise and return it.
3. Setup event listeners for "progress" and "end".
4. Resolve Promise *(and continue program)*
5. Get "end" event; run callback function and log "Successfully downloaded the stream!".

Assuming you want event 5 to happen before 4, you need to remove the `resolve(stream)` in `getStream()`, and move it to the end of the `on("end", {...})` callback function, like this:

```
.on('end', () => {
  progressBar.stop();
  logger.info('Successfully downloaded the stream!');
  resolve(stream);
});
```

Comment: I tried it but then it stucks here:
info:    Downloading from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Np8ibIagn3M ...
[Progress] [██████░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░] 14% | Downloaded: 1.02/7.15 MB | Elapsed Time: 6s^C

Comment: What does your `on("end", {...})` callback function look like now?